# jQuery inArray() returns -1 if array contains single element

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery inArray returns -1 if the array contains single element.

```
var a = Array(1);
console.log($.inArray(1,a));
```

This returns -1. But if the array contains 2 or more elements it works perfectly.

```
var a = Array(1,2,3);
console.log($.inArray(1,a));
```

Returns perfect position.

Comment: Good question Thanks we are all understood

Comment: @sudharsan have you upvoted this..? :)

Comment: this is confidential i didn't tell

Comment: @sudharsan oh.. :) Then i too wont tell you that i had upvoted this question and answer as well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what you seem to think,  `Array(1)` doesn't create an array with element `1` but an array of size `1`. That's a specific behavior you get when you pass only one argument and it's an integer.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) :

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer
>   between 0 and 2^32-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array
>   with length set to that number.

You should probably almost never use this `Array` constructor whose strange behavior leads to many bugs and which is mostly useless. Use this :

```
var a = [1];
```

Comment: `never (or almost never) use the Array constructor.` what is the reason for that..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy 1) its behavior is far too surprising. 2) it's mostly useless

Comment: Then how its returning perfect position with this:
`var a = Array(1,2,3);`

Comment: @ShashikumarMisal he explained that in his post. read carefully with patience.

Comment: @ShashikumarMisal Because then it's equivalent to [1,2,3]. Read the document I link to.

Comment: Ya, I got it there is a overloaded constructor for Array. If we pass single argument it will be length and if multiple then it will form an array...